# Use custom number format (exponential with custom suffix) on Kendo numeric textbox

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, number-formatting, exponent

I am trying to have a *custom format* on a **kendo numeric textbox** so that the number displays in **exponential format** with a **text string after it**.
For example the [format-string used by Kendo's Number Formatting](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberformatting) `e1 units/div` should render the number `1.22` as:

```
1.2e-0 units/div
```

### What I tried

#### (a) decimal format with custom suffix works (*not wanted* because not exponential format)

I can set a **decimal number format** that will allow **text after** as below:

```
//display number to 3 decimal places with text after
$("#numerictextbox").kendoNumericTextBox({
   format: "#.000 units/div" // bat need in exponential format
});
```

But I need exponential number formatting before the suffix.

#### (b) exponential format works (*not wanted*, because no custom suffix)

The code that displays the number in **exponential format** is below:

```
//display number as exponent with NO text after
$("#numerictextbox2").kendoNumericTextBox({
   format: "e1" //but need text "units/div" here after
});
```

#### exponential format with suffix (wanted; does not work)

But I can't get the exponential format to add the "`units/div`" string. Merely adding it to the string with e1 doesn't work:

```
//display number as exponent with text after
$("#numerictextbox2").kendoNumericTextBox({
   format: "e1 units/div" // what I want as output is: "1.2e+0 units/div"
});
```

Is there a way to do this or is this not possible with Kendo-UI?

### Research and Demo

The only examples I can find on here on stackoverflow are **how prevent displaying exponents**, whereas I specifically need to display the number as exponent.

A very simple *telerik dojo example* can be found [here](http://dojo.telerik.com/irOcUKes/4).

Comment: Very complete question! Especially that you included own code-trials plus demo-link is fine. Next time post directly what you want as solution (example code, example output) even if it's not working. You did research on SO. Great! Share it by including links to your findings (_examples that prevent displaying exponents_).

Comment: Thank you for your input, I have updated question with your suggestions